# How to fill forward value when specify one condition for another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am analyzing one table like below. There are several None values in `offer_id` column when the event column shows `transaction`. I will like to fill None by the value forward only if the previous event is `offer viewed`, otherwise, fill the None value as 0 or just leave it as none.

The dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'event': ['offer_received', 'offer_viewed','transaction', 'transaction', 'offer_received', 'transaction'], 'user':['A','A','A','A','A','A'], 'value':[0, 0, 1.09, 2.55, 0, 3.02], 'offer_id': ['0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7', '0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7', 'None', 'None', '3f207df678b143eea3cee63160fa8bed', 'None'], 'days':[0, 0.25, 9.75, 11, 0,9.75]})
```

```
event           user   value    offer_id                            days
offer received  A      0.00     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    0.00
offer viewed    A      0.00     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    0.25
transaction     A      1.09     None                                9.75
transaction     A      2.55     None                                11
offer received  A      0.00     3f207df678b143eea3cee63160fa8bed    0.00
transaction     A      3,02     None                                9.75
```

I have tried to use `df.offer_id.fillna(method = 'ffill')` but I just don´t know how can I put the condition on the event column when the previous event is `offer_viewed` then fill `offer_id` of `transaction` by using `(method = 'ffill')`.

My expect result will be like this:

```
event           user   value    offer_id                            days
offer received  A      0.00     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    0.00
offer viewed    A      0.00     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    0.2
transaction     A      1.09     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    9.75                   
transaction     A      2.55     0b1e1539f2cc45b7b9fa7c272da2e1d7    11                         
offer received  A      0.00     3f207df678b143eea3cee63160fa8bed    0.00
transaction     A      3,02     None                                9.75
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide an MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . You'll get faster help if people can copy-paste in something like `df = pd.DataFrame({'event': ['offer_received', ...` so they can get right to work on your problem without having to manually type in your data. Cheers!

Comment: Sure! I have add it in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get there with `shift()`, `ffill()`, and `where()`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'e': ['r', 'v', 't', 'r', 't'], 'oid': [1, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan]})
df
#    e  oid
# 0  r  1.0
# 1  v  1.0
# 2  t  NaN
# 3  r  2.0
# 4  t  NaN
df.oid = df.oid.ffill().where(df.e.shift() == 'v', df.oid)
df
#    e  oid
# 0  r  1.0
# 1  v  1.0
# 2  t  1.0
# 3  r  2.0
# 4  t  NaN
```

You can even skip the `ffill()` and use `shift()` twice:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'e': ['r', 'v', 't', 'r', 't'], 'oid': [1, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan]})

df.oid = df.oid.shift().where(df.e.shift() == 'v', df.oid)
df
#    e  oid
# 0  r  1.0
# 1  v  1.0
# 2  t  1.0
# 3  r  2.0
# 4  t  NaN
```

Comment: Hey Mike! Thanks so much for your answer. I have tried the both. But I don´t know why, it is not working. the "transaction" related offer_id columns still appear as None... Do you have one alternative?

Comment: Hey Mike! Sorry for the previous comment, it actually works!! Thanks very much!!!